# Integrating $f(x)=e^{2x}+\cos(4x)$ from $0$ to $ \pi$ with complex variables?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is it possible to integrate $f(x)=e^{2x}+\cos(4x)$ from $0$ to $ \pi$ with complex variables?

I read in the book *"Calculus with Complex numbers - John B.Reade"*, that you can replace $\cos(4x)$ with $e^{4ix}$ then get the integral, I did it but the answer wasn't the same as the answer I got when I did the integration with partial integration method.

The answer I got with partial integration method is : $\dfrac{e^{2\pi}-1}{10}$

The answer I got with doing the substitution of $\cos(4x)=e^{4ix}$, I got : $\dfrac{(2i-1)(e^\pi-1)}{10}$

What's wrong? and if the method is wrong why was it mentioned in the book? and why is it wrong?

Comment: Hi @Rootkit98! $$\color{red}{\Large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Comment: @Shaun Please refrain from using big text to welcome new users.

Comment: @Adobe: Okay. I didn't realise that it was a problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, since $\cos(4x)$ is not $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i4x}$ but $\frac12(\mathrm e^{\mathrm i4x}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i4x})$.

Comment: Right, but I think we can just replace the cos(4x) with e^(4ix) WHEN we're integrating FROM ZERO TO PI and if it's not true, why not?

Comment: No we cannot. Because the cosine is not equal to the complex exponential.

Answer (score 0):

The $\cos(4x)$ just goes to zero and the integral of $e^x$  is just $e^x + C$ but then the $C$ cancels since it's a definite integral $(0,\pi)$.  I think all you need to do is sub in for $2x$ by allowing $p = 2x$ and changing your limits accordingly and differential $\mathrm dx = \mathrm dp/2$.

Comment: I know the substitution method, the question is about applying complex variables to this question and then doing the integration.